# String compare exact in query MySQL

Tags: mysql, comparison, collation

I created table like that in MySQL:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `barcode`;
CREATE TABLE `barcode` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;


INSERT INTO `barcode` VALUES ('1', 'abc');

INSERT INTO `barcode` VALUES ('2', 'abc ');
```

Then I query data from table barcode:

```sql
SELECT * FROM barcode WHERE `code` = 'abc ';
```

The result is:

```
+-----+-------+
|  id | code  |
+-----+-------+
|  1  |  abc  |
+-----+-------+
|  2  |  abc  |
+-----+-------+
```

But I want the result set is only 1 record. I workaround with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM barcode WHERE `code` = binary 'abc ';
```

The result is 1 record. But I'm using NHibernate with MySQL for generating query from mapping table. So that how to resolve this case?

Comment: Next time, take a look at how your question is going to come out (there's a preview box beneath your text field), and if it looks a mess, fix it :). Use a generous amount of the `{}` button on top for code.....

Comment: Could you provide NHibenate mappings, and methods you use to generate query? Why do you use native-SQL with NHibernate. I think, you should use Criteria API or HQL.

Comment: from the docs: ["All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR and VARCHAR values in MySQL are compared without regard to any trailing spaces"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Answer (score 9):

There is no other fix for it. Either you specify a single comparison as being `binary` or you set the whole database connection to `binary`. (doing `SET NAMES binary`, which may have other side effects!)

Basically, that 'lazy' comparison is a **feature** of MySQL which is hard coded. To disable it (on demand!), you can use a `binary` compare, what you apparently already do. This is not a 'workaround' but the real fix.

from the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR and VARCHAR values in MySQL are compared without regard to any trailing spaces

Of course there are plenty of other possiblities to achieve the same result from a user's perspective, i.e.:

- `WHERE field = 'abc ' AND CHAR_LENGTH(field) = CHAR_LENGTH('abc ')`
- `WHERE field REGEXP 'abc[[:space:]]'`

**The problem** with these is that they effectively disable fast index lookups, so your query always results in a full table scan. With huge datasets that makes a big difference.

**Again:** `PADSPACE` is default for MySQLs [VAR]CHAR comparison. You can (and should) disable it by using `BINARY`. This is the indended way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a [regular expression matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) :

```
SELECT * FROM barcode WHERE `code` REGEXP 'abc[[:space:]]'
```

Comment: Downvoter care to help the rest of us understand what you think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I guess this answer was downvoted because `REGEXP` disables index lookups and always results in a full table scan. If you *can avoid regex* in mysql, you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

i was just working on case just like that when using LIKE with wildcard (%) resulting in an unexpected result. While searching i also found `STRCMP(text1, text2)` under string comparison feature of mysql which compares two string. however using BINARY with LIKE solved the problem for me.

```
SELECT * FROM barcode WHERE `code` LIKE BINARY 'abc ';
```

Comment: FYI: While your answer appears plausible, it has appeared in the 'low quality posts' queue after being flagged for deletion. I suspect this is because it is a code only answer without explanation.

To be clear here, I didn't flag it so I don't know why it was flagged. However I do see a lot of code only answers appearing in that queue, so I have taken to adding comments to them so the responder is aware of this.

Comment: my bad. i should add some explanation. thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you only want one result, you could use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM barcode WHERE `code` = 'abc ' LIMIT 1;
```

To do exact string matching you could use `Collation`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM barcode
 WHERE code COLLATE utf8_bin = 'abc';
```

Comment: This is not answering the OP - the problem seems to be that they want to have only exact string matches, including leading and trailing spaces. Using `LIMIT` does not achieve this.

Comment: I don't think your proposed use of `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` will make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM barcode WHERE `code` = 'abc ' 
AND CHAR_LENGTH(`code`)=CHAR_LENGTH('abc ');
```

Comment: Downvoter care to help the rest of us understand what you think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I guess this answer was downvoted because `WHERE F(x) = F(y)` is causing a lot of computational overhead, because the function must be executed two times for each row in the result dataset. In this case it's not too bad, because there is at least one simple `WHERE` condition. If `F(x) = F(y)` was the *only* condition, it would result in a full table scan, which is something you should avoid.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence right after the one quoted by [Kaii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10346886/86072) basically says "use `LIKE`" :

> [“Comparison” in this context does not include the LIKE pattern-matching operator, for which trailing spaces are significant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

and the example below shows that `'Monty' = 'Monty '` is true, but not `'Monty' LIKE 'Monty '`.

However, if you use `LIKE`, beware of literal strings containing the `'%'`, `'_'` or `'\'` characters : `'%'` and `'_'` are wildcard characters, `'\'` is used to escape sequences.

Comment: nice catch. but when using `LIKE` one should also be aware of the other side effects of the `LIKE` operator. Examples: `"A" LIKE "a"` equals true, `"a" LIKE "_"` also equals true. As a workaround to the case-insensitivity of `LIKE` the manual offers a `LIKE BINARY` operation .. 
And that is where the circle is closed: `BINARY` is the real fix. 
If you don't believe me, see the manual for [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). The only difference between `= BINARY` and `LIKE BINARY` is that `LIKE` has more side effects. Sorry ;)

Comment: `"A" LIKE "a"` depends on the collation, doesn't it ? just like `=`. I wasn't aware of the `"_"` special character, though. It sure does complicate the corner cases. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're right, `"A" LIKE "a"` depends on collation. `"A" COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE "a" COLLATE utf8_bin` does return `0`.